# Are there generally accepted standards for frequency of bugs?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, development-process, scrum

Are there any sort of general standards, levels or percentages for how many issues should be reopened due to a bug being found during testing?

Of course this will vary but I am looking for a general guideline. I feel like 90% should go through about, without being reopened.

Comment: There's no clear rule about that. It is also crucial what has been defined in the Definition of Ready and Definition of Done. In addition there is what you have defined in the bug guidelines and in the test planning, if you have defined something.

Comment: Three doewnvotes for new question by new user and no attempt to update question or guide them.  Please CONSIDER HELPING PEOPLE BY UPDATING THEIR QUESTION. c'mon folks, please change your motivation from 'Close, not appropriate~' to 'help'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no general guideline for this.

This depends on how experienced/good the devs are, how new the technology is they might be using, how complex or new the application is they are building, etc.

For example if it's a long ongoing project were only small changes are done, you should find next to no bugs, however in a new project that is just being started you might have a failure rate of 50% or more.

The only number that could be decided on upfront is how many % of the test cases you need passed/successful before testing can give their "GO", which is generally an agreement that is made with the customer/business/whoever is paying or responsible for the project.

Answer (score 1):

100% should be "re-opened" :) I always find something worth discussing when developing new features.

> Start testing the application by **intend** of finding defects/errors.
>   Don't think beforehand that there will not be any bugs in the
>   application. If you test the application by intention of finding
>   defects you will definitely succeed to find those **subtle** defects also.

Today something worked functionally perfectly, but the logs showed exceptions. Although it was totally explainable why this was happening. We discussed it and decided to change this, because operational users might start asking questions.

When talking about re-opening in the context of defect-leakage to production. I would say it depends. Skill levels, complexity, risks, etcs...

Answer (score 0):

The more bug we found, the more value the tester brought. For new features, we can open a lot of bugs but it's not the same with regression test plan.
So suggestion is we should find at least 3 bugs per 100 test cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in a software testing company there is no standard guidelines. Actually if the issues are getting reopened due to a bug then all of them should reopened.

Because if we do not reopen then there would be chances that this would penetrate into the release and at the end will impact the users. Moreover we also need to make a track of the same that how many are reopened and what was the root cause so that responsibility of the same should be defined.